# JAAS Authentication to Windows Domain

Tags: authentication, kerberos, jaas

Using a provided username, password, and domain name, how can I retrieve a boolean value indicating if a user has successfully authenticated with a primary domain controller? Authentication should be performed using the Kerberos protocol for windows domain controllers. Thanks in advance, Dan

Answer (score 3):

There's a free implementation of a windows-only JAAS login module and of an SSO Negotiate (Kerberos/NTLM) authenticator: [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com).

Comment: Haven't used it but looks great.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either write your own or use third party Authentication Module for that. When I was doing this, there was nothing available from JDK, so I used [this tool](http://free.tagish.net/jaas/doc.html). Note that it's GPL, but you can learn from there. You will have to create conf. file describing your authentication module and feed it into your JVM with **java.security.auth.login.config** property (e.g. using -D, or either way). In case of Tagish it looks something like this:

NTLogin
{
    com.tagish.auth.win32.NTSystemLogin required returnNames=true returnSIDs=false defaultDomain="domain";
};

Another thing you will need is to specify kerberos configuration file via **java.security.krb5.conf** property. I don't have the details of this file handy, but you can easily find it on the net -- google about for krb5.conf. Settings in this file will have to match your windows domain and other windows specific settings.

It's a bit tricky to configure, but for me it worked very well, pretty robust.